# python using multiple conditions with numpy where

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I have a giant array called AllDays storing datetime.

I generated an array which stores day of week information for each day.

I am trying to extract the weekends only from the original datetime array AllDays.

So, from the day of week I am trying the following:

```
DayOfWeek = np.asarray([x.weekday() for x in AllDays])
#AllDays stores datetime objects
ind = np.where(DayOfWeek == 0 or DayOfWeek == 6) #gives Error
```

I aim to use it as following to extract only the weekends:

```
weekends = AllDays[ind]
```

Error at line

```
ind = np.where(DayOfWeek == 0 or DayOfWeek == 6)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: You could define a variable `weekend_indexes = (0, 6)` and check `DayOfWeek in weekend_indexes`.  Then you'd have a single condition to put in your `np.where()`

Comment: The `ValueError` comes up frequently.  It indicates that an array is being used in a context that expects a scalar True/False (e.g. the `or`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the "or" which is not defined for numpy boolean arrays. You can just use a sum instead:

```
np.where((DayOfWeek == 0) + (DayOfWeek == 6))
```

edit: You can also use the bitwise or operator:

```
np.where((DayOfWeek == 0) | (DayOfWeek == 6))
```

which gives the same result but is somewhat nicer as we are working with booleans...

Comment: The element-wise OR operator is `|`. `np.where((DayOfWeek == 0) | (DayOfWeek == 6))`

Comment: Yeah, that is even nicer. Thanks!

Comment: because true + true = true does not really make sense as far as logics are concerned. In the implementation, it works just as good.

Comment: The `()` are equally important.  You want to evaluate the `==` first.